# How to load data from E-goi using REST API google script

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script

I want to access data from e-goi API and in documentation I got a .jar file. There are no examples with RESP API so I don't know how access it directly.
As I'm new to this kind of program, I would like some help to access the data directly using REST API google script program.

I tried this code:

```
function myFunction() {
  var url = 'http://api.e-goi.com/v2/rest.php?apikey=04cc5ea9d2d266a376c07ff4f12e077be40bbf51&method=getUserData';
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {'muteHttpExceptions': true});
  //var data = JSON.parse(response);
  Logger.log(responAccording to the se);
}
```

And I got this response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Egoi_Api generator="zend" version="1.0"><getUserData><response>NO_USERNAME_AND_PASSWORD_AND_APIKEY</response><status>success</status></getUserData></Egoi_Api>
```

According to the E-goi API, the method getUserData don't need username ou password, only the apikey that is already in the command.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How will you execute java in JavaScript? I don't think it's possible.

Comment: No, in fact I really confused. I know a little programming but not in this area. I've seen that it's possible to use html with javascript with php and css. I have not yet understood exactly how they relate.

Comment: what I want is to query the E-goi API directly from google script to put the data in a spreadsheet. It should probably be done using urlFetch.

Answer (score 2):

Java is not JavaScript. You can't simply run Java code inside Javascript.

It looks like you want to access the RESTful API using Google Apps Script, not use the Java wrapper provided by e-goi. This is possible using `UrlFetch` on the API provided; see [Google's guide on External APIs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/external) for general information on how to make an API request, and [e-goi's](https://api-docs.e-goi.com/api/v2/#) documentation for information specific to using their API. Especially note the required query parameters for each potential API method (e.g., API key) and how those can be included in your url in `fetch()`

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I was able to study a little more about the urlFetch commands in google script. and I was able to mount this command:

Comment: function myFunction() {
  var url = 'http://api.e-goi.com/v2/rest.php?apikey=04cc5ea9d2d266a376c07ff4f12e077be40bbf51&method=getUserData';
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {'muteHttpExceptions': true});
  Logger.log(response);
}

Comment: and I got this answer:
[19-05-26 15:39:16:041 BRT] <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Egoi_Api generator="zend" version="1.0"><getUserData><response>NO_USERNAME_AND_PASSWORD_AND_APIKEY</response><status>success</status></getUserData></Egoi_Api>

Comment: But loking at e-goi documentation, the Method "getUserData" don't need Username and password, need only the Apikey that is already in the command. What could be wrong?

Comment: You might want to delete that and repost it without your API key. A few things I would check: Is it `?apikey`, or `?api_key`? Are you sure the key is valid?  What happens if you use the `checklogin` method (trying with api key? username/password?)

Comment: Don't worry, that key is not valid anymore. Thanks :)   The correct is apikey and I've tried Checklogin, GetClientData and GetUserData methods, all with the answers.

Comment: The problem was in the syntax. I asked to the support and they gave me this command:

Comment: http://api.e-goi.com/v2/rest.php?method=getUserData&type=json&functionOptions[apikey]=xxxxxxxxxxx

Comment: With this command, worked fine. Thanks for the tips and attention!!